# Can a character have downtime while on the road?

Tags: dnd-5e, travel, downtime

If the party is on the road, traveling somewhere, and a member is not walking or actively doing anything (ie: being carried or riding a wagon) can they use that time to do downtime activities?

Comment: Any specific downtime activities? Are we talking training in how to drive the wagon you're riding in, or building a stronghold?

Comment: Agreed w @MarkWells, an example of which specific activities might help focus answers.

Comment: Also, is this travel otherwise the part of downtime, ie. between adventures? Or is it supposed to be part of an adventure?

Comment: This question is concise and well-focused on a broader issue well-within scope. Other questions concerning specific activities exist and may be asked, but do not warrant this question to be closed.

Answer (score 13):

### Downtime activities happen between, not during adventures.

Downtime Activities specifically describes time between adventures that characters engage in other non-adventuring activities (DMG 126-131).

Typically characters travel for 8 hours/day (DMG 242-243, compare to forced March PHB 181, and Time PHB 181-183).

Regarding other activities (PHB 183) than navigating, foraging, drawing maps, tracking, and staying alert/hidden and noticing threats during an adventure it is up to the DM's discretion:

> However, a character not watching for danger can do one of the
>   following activities instead, or some other activity with the DM’s
>   permission.

So if you want to do other activities such as described in the downtime section, those activities are at the discretion of your DM, but they are not considered downtime activities as these by definition only happen between adventures.

Comment: Yes, but not all travel is adventuring. Sometimes it's just travel.

Comment: All game time is adventuring unless linking between adventures (DMG 125) that you can fill with downtime, whether downtime can be used to travel is table-dependent. My answer covers this if you happen to downtime activity travel, then you are already engaging in downtime activities. (Though none of this applies to the specific situation op describes and answers a different question than the perfectly reasonable and focused question that op stated)